# Reducing query time in table with unsorted timeranges

Tags: c++, sql, sqlite

I had a question regarding this matter some days ago, but I'm still wondering about how to tune my performance on this query.

I have a table looking like this (SQLite)

```
CREATE TABLE ZONEDATA (
TIME INTEGER  NOT NULL,
CITY INTEGER  NOT NULL,
ZONE INTEGER  NOT NULL,
TEMPERATURE DOUBLE,
SERIAL INTEGER ,
FOREIGN KEY (SERIAL) REFERENCES ZONES,
PRIMARY KEY ( TIME, CITY, ZONE));
```

I'm running a query like this:

```
SELECT temperature, time, city, zone from zonedata
WHERE (city = 1) and (zone = 1) and (time BETWEEN x AND y);
```

x and y are variables which may have several hundred thousands variables between them.

temperature ranges from -10.0 to 10.0, city and zone from 0-20 (in this case it is 1 and 2, but can be something else). Records are logged continuously with intervals on about 5-6 seconds from different zones and cities. This creates a lot of data, and does not necessarily mean that every record is logged in correct order of time.

The question is how I can optimize retrieval of records in a big time range (where records are not sorted 100% correctly by time). This can take a lot of time, especially when I'm retrieving from several cities and zones. That means running the mentioned query with different parameters several times. What I'm looking for is specific changes to the query, table structure (preferably not) or other changeable settings.

My application using this is btw implemented in c++.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your data already is sorted by `Time`.

By having a Primary Key on `(Time, City, Zone)` all the records with that same `Time` value will be next to each other.  *(Unless you have specified a CLUSTER INDEX elsewhere, though I'm not familiar enough with SQLite to know if that's possible.)*

In your particular case, however, that means the records that you want are not next to each other.  Instead they're in bunches.  Each bunch of records will have `(city=1, zone=1)` and have the same Time value.  One bunch for Time1, another bunch for Time2, etc, etc.

It's like putting it all in Excel and ordering by Time, then by City, then by Zone.

To bunch ALL the records you want (for the same City and Zone) change that to `(City, Zone, Time)`.

Note, however, that if you also have a query for `all cities and zones but a time = ???` the key I suggested won't be perfect for that, your original key would be better.

For that reason you may wish/need to add different indexes in different orders, for different queries.

This means that to give you a specific recommended solution we need to know the specific query you will be running.  My suggested key/index order may be ideal for your simplified example, but the real-life scenario may be different enough to warrant a different index altogether.

Answer (score 0):

You can index those columns, it will sort it internally for faster query but you will not see it.

Comment: Ok, I have experimented a little bit with that approach. You mean something like this: CREATE INDEX zone_indx on zonedata(zone) ?

Answer (score 0):

For a database `between` is hard to optimize.  One way out of this is adding extra fields so you can replace `between` with an `=`.  For example, if you add a `day` field, you could query for:

```
where  city = 1 and zone = 1 and day = '2012-06-22' and 
       time between '2012-06-22 08:00' and '2012-06-22 12:00'
```

This query is relatively fast with an index on `city, zone, day`.

This requires thought to pick the proper extra fields.  It requires additional code to maintain the field.  If this query is in an important performance path of your application, it might be worth it.

Comment: On what basis is `BETWEEN` hard to optimise?  It's just a range seek, surely?  The increase in cost comes not because of `BETWEEN` but when the range field is first/early in the index, and is highly selective.  If the field is last in the index then there is a single range seek for each city/zone, and that range seek is extremely simple and quick.

Comment: You're probably right.  In my experience databases are (too) hesitant to use a range seek, but that's probably less true for a clustered index.

Comment: so would this added "=" increase the speed?